# Сконвертировать строку байт в массив float PHP

Tags: php, python, byte

Получаю строку байт длиной, например, в 88 байт в big-endian. Известно что каждые 4 байта это число типа float.

т.е количество закодированных чисел получается 88/4=22 числа.

Из документации PHP: `G float (машинно-зависимые размер, порядок байт big endian)`

Делаем:

```
b_size = 88/4;

unpack('4G', $all_buffer) // Что сюда не хватает?
```

Для Python сделано так:

```
b_size = 88/4;

struct.unpack('!%df' % b_size, all_buffer)
```

где:
`!` - big-endian
`%d` - указатель на int b_size
`f` - float

Вопрос: как раскодировать строку байт на PHP?

Comment: В той же документации написано что-то про « Для осуществления этого необходимо обозначить различные коды форматов и разделить их с помощью слеша /.» http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unpack.php

Comment: Так у меня же один код формата...

Comment: Блин, в моём php даже примеры из документации не запускаются... Может, лучше останетесь на Python?)

Comment: Звёздочки не хватает, и 4 не нужно. `unpack('G*', $all_buffer)`

Comment: или `unpack('G22', $all_buffer)` если хочется указать количество. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pack.php

Comment: @Alexey Ten не помогает.... А если сделать bin2hex($all_buffer)..

Comment: Так а что не работает то? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c507493d8b592e1928a3b8f42adbdc18f69c4c1e

Comment: В браузере моя строка выглядит как-то так: �ZHd�/ʺ�1� и ничего не происходит var_dump(unpack('G*',$all_buffer)); ->bool(false)

Comment: А версия пхп какая?

Comment: 5.6, да и это большая проблема...